# Why is gem environment different in RubyMine and in terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rubymine

My terminal gem environment does not match with my Rubymine one.
In terminal it gives:

```
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/george/.gem/ruby/1.9.3/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/george/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-12
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/george/.gem/ruby/1.9.3
     - /Users/george/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
```

whereas in RubyMine it gives:

```
EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/george/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin
SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/george/.gem/specs
RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  ruby
  x86_64-darwin-12
GEM PATHS:
   /Users/george/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
   /Users/george/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
```

There seems to be a confusion about gem location and I dont know how to fix it.

I am using chruby to control ruby versions installed with ruby-build
The application is Rails 3.2.17

The full output in terminal and Rubymine are below:

Terminal:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-02-22 patchlevel 392) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/george/.gem/ruby/1.9.3
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/george/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/george/.gem/ruby/1.9.3/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/george/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-12
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/george/.gem/ruby/1.9.3
     - /Users/george/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/george/.gem/ruby/1.9.3/bin
     - /Users/george/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin
     - /Users/george/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /Users/george/bin
     - /opt/X11/bin
```

RubyMine:

```
RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-02-22 patchlevel 392) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]
INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/george/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/george/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby
EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/george/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin
SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/george/.gem/specs
RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  ruby
  x86_64-darwin-12
GEM PATHS:
   /Users/george/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
   /Users/george/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
GEM CONFIGURATION:
   :update_sources => true
   :verbose => true
   :backtrace => false
   :bulk_threshold => 1000
REMOTE SOURCES:
   https://rubygems.org/
SHELL PATH:
   /Users/george/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin
   /usr/bin
   /bin
   /usr/sbin
   /sbin
   /usr/local/bin
   /Users/george/bin
   /opt/X11/bin
   /usr/local/bin
----------------------
IDE: RubyMine 6.0.3, build #RM-133.632
OS: Mac OS X 10.9.2[x86_64]
Java: 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609
RubyMine SDK Environment:
Sdk: ruby-1.9.3-p392
Sdk Version: ver.1.9.3p392 ( revision 39386) p392
Ruby Interpreter: /Users/george/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby
RVM Sdk: no
RVM Home: /usr/local/rvm
Sdk Language Level: 1.9
Sdk Load Path:
     ~/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1
     ~/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.5.0
     ~/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby
     ~/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1
     ~/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.5.0
     ~/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
     ~/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1
     ~/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.5.0
     /Applications/RubyMine.app/rubystubs193
Sdk Gem paths: 
     ~/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems
     ~/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems
     ~/.rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems
     ~/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems
```

Answer (score 7):

Seems like RubyMine uses a wrong ruby version. To fix this:

1. In RubyMine go to Preferences -> Ruby SDK and Gems
2. click ruby- in the middle window
3. then click any gem in the right window and check gem path in the bottom window
4. If the path not the same as you get in terminal
5. click + in the middle window, choose New local... and add path to the desired ruby bin directory.
   This should fix an issue.

Answer (score 1):

By default RubyMine search for the file `.ruby-version` in your project root directory, then sets the Ruby version to use with rvm, overriding the default rvm configuration.

To solve this you have 2 options:

- edit the `.ruby-version` file to the desired version.
- o as @anton-chikin says, you can manually change the SDK used in RubyMine -> Preferences -> Ruby SDK and Gems

Comment: It might happen even if you don't have a .ruby-version